# JavaScript code in iFrame references parent would like to set it as null

Tags: javascript, iframe, cross-domain

I have a page where I am including another webpage using an iframe. It is on a different domain. The iframe webpage contains some JavaScript code that looks at the partent:

> parent.window.scrollTo(0,0)

As the code is on a differnt domain I am getting Access Denied. Is there anyway that I can pass into the iframe that the parent is null to stop the error?

Answer (score 0):

See Same Origin Policy. You can't access the parent from the `iframe` on a different domain or vice versa.